# Bootstrap 3.0 Text is coming after 2 input elements when it is coded before.

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap

With Bootstrap 3.0, I am have a couple of questions/issues:

1) For learning, how is possible to have the div with class col-sm-5 small than the child div elements that are specified longer with class="col-sm-4" + class="col-sm-4" which equals 8?

2) I want "Pick A Date" text to come before the 2 input elements. However, it's coming after them which makes no sense to me.

```
<form name="dateFrom">
    <div class="form-group well col-sm-5">
        <div class="form-group"> 
            Pick A Date
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="From date" name="search" class="form-control">
            </div>
            <div class="col-sm-4">
                <input type="text" class="form-control datepicker" placeholder="To date" name="search1" class="form-control">
            </div>
        </div><!-- /input-group -->
    </div><!-- /.col-lg- -->
</form>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**1)** the widths of the columns are defined in percent, `col-sm-5` has is 5/12 of the width of its parent and the `col-sm-4` is 4/12 of the width of its parent which is in your case the `form-group`.

**2)** the elements with the class `col-sm-` have `float: left`, as your text `Pick A Date` does not have any floating attribute, the two `div` with `col-sm-` float to the left thats why your text appears on the right. If you want it in the correct order surround it with a `div` and add e.g. `col-sm-4`  to it.